# Values of variables for pattern matching

Tags: haskell

Just staring with Haskell. I want to define some elements to easily create morphisms between them.

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"

g a = a --Problem is here
g b = a --Problem is here
```

**Edit** The problem is that haskell treats "a" in "g a" as a variable, but I actually want the value of the "a" defined above. Conceptually a want this

```
g (valueOf a) = a --Problem is here
g (valueOf b) = a --Problem is here
```

Where `valueOf` is a magic function that would give me

```
g "foo" = a
g "bar" = a
```

Comment: g is no id because: g b = a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"

g x | x==a = a
    | x==b = a
```

or

```
g "foo" = a
g "bar" = a
```

---

When you pattern match using a variable as in

```
g a = ...
```

the variable `a` is a local variable, bound to the argument of the function. Even if `a` was already defined globally, the code above will not use the value of the global `a` to perform a comparison.

This semantics allows to reason locally about your code. Consider this code as an example:

```
f 2 x = 4
f c d = 0
```

Just by looking at the above definition you can see that `f 2 3` is `4`. This is not changed if later on you add a definition for `x` as follows:

```
x = 5

f 2 x = 4
f c d = 0
```

If the match semantics compared the second argument to `5`, now we would have `f 2 3` equal to `0`. This would make reasoning about the function definitions harder, so most (if not all) functional languages such as Haskell use "local" variables for pattern matching, ignoring the possible global definitions for such variables.

---

A more adventurous alternative is to use [view patterns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
a = "foo"
b = "bar"
g ((==a) -> True) = ...
g ((==b) -> True) = ...
```

I am not a fan of this approach though, since I find standard patterns with guards to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I see the point. But still think there should be an operator for telling the interpreter to use the definition in the outer scope.

Comment: Guards such as `x | x==a = ... | x==b = ...` do not require much typing. Otherwise, you may want to experiment with [view patterns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns), but they seem overkill for this task IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies in advance if this is a complete misunderstanding of what
you want to accomplish but wouldn't something like this do?

```
Data Obj = A | B

g A = A
g B = A

f A = "foo"
f B = "bar"
```

You want a predefined set of objects, yes?